# Id in the beginning of the Route in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a situation where I want a route in my application so that the application's index method can recognize this `http://www.website.com/ID`

and also, `http://www.website.com/Controller/Action` should also work.

The problem is that, when I set up the route corresponding to the first URL, the route for the second URL does not work (even if I set up a separate route for that).

Please tell me what am I doing wrong here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "DefaultWithID",
    "{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Assuming:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Both: `/123` and `/Home/Index/123` work fine.

Comment: This leaves open the possibility of the ambiguous (and wrongly mapped in this case, I believe) route of `/home`.  You would want it to map the same as `/home/index` but it won't.  Without a suitable route constraint, it will select the first route and match as if it were `/home/index/home`.

Answer (score 2):

Does the `ID` value have some distinguishing characteristic that would allow you to tell the difference between it and a controller name?  For example, is it numeric?  If so, you can set up a constraint on the first route so that it only matches ids.  This would allow other requests to fall through to the second (default) route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "IdRoute",
    "{id}",
    new { controller = "home", action = "get" },
    new { id = "\d+" } // match ids that consist of 1 or more digits
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    new { controller = "home", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```